# Слетел перевод ссылки на улучшение метки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Если выбрать любую метку, то можно наблюдать такое:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подхватил старый перевод:

> Улучшить описание метки

Почему-то еще никто не заметил, что на картинке еще «Top users» без перевода. Тоже поправил:

> Лучшие участники

На сайте после подкачки Transifex и пересборки движка.

Comment: "Почему-то еще никто не заметил" - Наверное как-то связано с тем, что английские надписи постоянно появляются в случайных местах сайта уже месяца три, так что в итоге все привыкли к ним и при беглом просмотре не замечают.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight строки по идее уже должны перестать слетать [по этому поводу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306091/339911). Но, конечно, будут слетать по другим :) В текущей ситуации получается будто старая строка была написана с маленькой буквы, и сбросилось после того, как стало с прописной.